# Migration to DIY

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55443/how-do-i-repair-a-broken-cable-in-a-retractable-handle-suitcase?noredirect=1#comment112786_55443) (which I think is clear and demonstrates effort in the question formulation) seems to fit here, observing tags like [luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage), [hand-luggage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage+hand-luggage), [luggage-gear](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage+gear), [luggage-storage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luggage+luggage-storage),
 and questions like [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45400/can-a-rip-on-a-suitcase-be-repaired-with-iron-on-patches?rq=1) and [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34095/how-to-dispose-of-a-broken-suitcase-at-an-airport?rq=1), TO the [DIY community](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/74078/how-do-i-repair-a-broken-cable-in-a-retractable-handle-suitcase) where it is *not* on-topic as described on [that community's page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  (I had checked there before posting here.)   Why was the question migrated there, in terms that could help guide future decisions proposed for migration along the same path?

Answer (score 3):

Well I did ask in a comment on the Q whether it might be better on DIY, mainly because I felt repair work was off-topic here.  It's not a travel question, I don't think. Others might disagree.

Then you can see that the mod migrated it.

It certainly hasn't received close votes on DIY, so they don't (so far) seem to consider it off topic there. However, I'm no DIY expert, so I can't comment on that.

IMHO, if it wasn't migrated, it'd likely have been closed as off-topic.  So far, it looks like it's doing better there (no close/down votes).

Comment: Should all of the questions and questions under the tags linked to in the question above be closed as off-topic here?

Comment: No, and that's a straw-man argument. It's not the tag that's in question, it's the question that is off-topic.  Certainly questions under the tags can still be on topic.  For example, where to store luggage in airport x would cover a lot of those topics, and be a travelling question.

Comment: OK, so luggage-storage is on topic here.  How about the others?
The question is clearly NOT on topic for DIY as described on that community's page.

Comment: All those tags have on-topic questions, otherwise they wouldn't exist. However not all questions that use these tags are on topic. It's still not gotten any close votes on DIY, so I think your fears of it being off-topic there are misplaced, but like I said, I can't comment on that more.

Comment: As predicted, the question was closed as off-topic there.  What makes the question off-topic here?